# how to download the applications from my cloudbees account to local directory for modification

Tags: eclipse, grails, deployment, download, cloudbees

I am trying to create and deploy a grails application on the cloud bees i tried using both, cloud-bees sdk and as well as the eclipse sdk . I don't no much how to use the cloud bees sdk so I tried using the eclipse sdk. 
In eclipse SDK the command is being executed but only thing fails is that it throws an error, now I want to create and deploy the application on the cloud.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CloudBees SDK to deploy a Grails application on CloudBees platform.

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Grails).

Basically, you can see on the doc these are the steps in the case you don't need database binding:

1. Create your application

   bees app:create -a my-app jvmPermSize=128
2. Setting the Grails Environment of the Tomcat server

   bees config:set -a my-app -P grails.env=production
3. Deploy your application

   bees app:deploy -a my-app target/my-app-0.1.war

You can generate the war file of your application using the command below:

```
grails war
```